# Horizontal scrollbar does not show when content in the table cell overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, dgrid

I am working with dgrid tables. I have a table with single column, and each column cell have some contents within it. When my cell content is really big, i would like to show a scrollbar, so the user can scroll and view the rest of the content. However in my table, the scrollbar does not show in this case, but if i use the dgrid columnResizer to expand the column, then the scrollbar shows up till the expanding width. If the width is less than the content, then the rest of the content will still remain invisible. Here is the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vrwe7dn5/

This is my CSS-

```
#grid{
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
.dgrid-scroller{
  overflow:auto;
  position: relative;
}
.dgrid-content{
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are using, .dgrid-scroller{} is only for the column. To make the content scrollable, you would have to apply overflow-x:scroll on the td's themselves.

Comment: No, That does not work correctly. Setting properties on td tag, will set scroll on all 'td' tags contained in the table. So each cell would have it own scrollbar.

Comment: Using js/jquery you could get the class .dgrid-cell and any that contain content of a certain length, you could add an overflow class to it to make it scrollable.